# How do I install Ruby Shoes?

Tags: ruby, user-interface

A lot of information seems stale since _why took his toys and went home, yet I would love to use it as a educational tool for my family.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[_why](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Why_the_lucky_stiff)'s gone, but his toys have been carefully preserved by [many](http://viewsourcecode.org/why/).

You can still find [Shoes](http://shoes.heroku.com/) online, with documentation, tutorials, and all.  I haven't tested the [installers](http://github.com/shoes/shoes/downloads), but [sources](http://github.com/shoes/shoes) definitely still work on my Linux x86_64 system, with mild changes (one instance of s/ungif/gif/ in Rakefile).